# Images missing when using ProxyPassMatch to redirect aspx requests

Tags: apache, iis

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mine.abc.def.edu
ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*\.aspx.*) http://mine.abc.def.edu:8080/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

I am running IIS on port 8080, and Apache on port 80.  I have gotten the above in the apache config to successfully redirect ASP.NET pages to IIS, but the images on the pages are missing.  I was thinking I need some sort of Reverse Proxy rule that says "if the request for the image or other resource is coming from a aspx page, then add port 8080", but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you want Apache or IIS to deliver the images and other static content?

Comment: I want IIS to deliver them if they are in the directory or subdirectory of the aspx page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a different virtual host name, or subdirectory, for the IIS server?  That way you can match on the host header in your mod_proxy setup.

Comment: I'm not sure about using a different hostname.  I did think about using a subdirectory, but it wouldn't be ideal.